# Venn diagram: how split the set in two parts

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

With this code

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[pattern=north east lines,pattern color=yellow] (4.5,2) ellipse[x radius = 3, 
y radius = 1.5];
\node[yellow!60!black] [at={(2,1.5)}] {$S_T$};
\node[red!40!black] [at={(3.4,1.5)}] {$S_{SR}$};
\draw [pattern=north west lines,pattern color=red] (5,2) ellipse [x radius =2.4, 
y radius = 1.4];
\draw [fill, color=white] (5.5,2) ellipse [x radius =1.8, y radius = 1];
\node [at = {(5,2)}] {$A$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I can obtain the following figure:

[image]

I would like to modify the sets labeled by A and S_{SR} in such a way the middle size ellipse is splitted in two parts by a line: the left side should be labeled by S_{SR}, whereas the right one should be labeled by A.

Below a sketch of the changes I would like to apply (colorless for simplicity):

[image]

Comment: Please make your code compilable.

Comment: @hpekristiansen: thank you. I edited the post.

Comment: can you provide a sketch of the changes you want to apply?

Comment: @Excelsior: thank you, I provided an example (colorless and without labels for simplicity)

Comment: @Mark should the pattern also change (left side red pattern, right side white)?

Comment: [One solution different from Excelsior's one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/592128/making-ellipses-with-tikz/592168#592168) (which is great too).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this the result you want?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,intersections}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{contour}
\contournumber{64}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[pattern=north east lines,pattern color=yellow] (4.5,2) ellipse[x radius=3, y radius=1.5];
                
        \draw [name path=a, fill=white] (5,2) ellipse [x radius =2.4, y radius = 1.4];
        \draw[name path=b] (5,0.6) to[out=135, in=315] (5,3.4);
        
        \draw [
            pattern=north west lines,
            pattern color=red, 
            intersection segments={
                of=a and b,sequence={R2--L2}
            }
        ];
        
        \node[yellow!60!black] at (2,1.5) {\contour{white}{$S_T$}};
        \node[red!40!black] at (3.4,1.5) {\contour{white}{$S_{SR}$}};
        \node at (5.5,1.5) {\contour{white}{$A$}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Nice use of `intersection segments`